# Why implicit class in Scala must reside in another trait/class/object?

Tags: scala

Based on the scala documentation: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html, the implicit class has three restrictions, and the very first one, I quote here, is

> They must be defined inside another trait/class/object

What is the intuition/reason to explain/justify such a restriction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An implicit class decomposes into a "normal" class and an implicit method that instantiates the class:

```
implicit class IntOps(i: Int) { def squared = i * i }
```

Is rewritten as

```
class IntOps(i: Int) { def squared = i * i }
implicit def IntOps(i: Int) = new IntOps(i)
```

But in Scala, you cannot define a method (`def IntOps`) outside of an object or a class. That is why.