# Why can there not be any method, member or object in scope with the same name as the implicit class

Tags: scala

> There may not be any method, member or object in scope with the same
> name as the implicit class.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html

Just wondering why this is the case? I know normal classes can have companion objects, why not implicit ones? Is it for the same reason as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583616/why-implicit-class-in-scala-must-reside-in-another-trait-class-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be potential name clashes because

```
implicit class fooOps(v: TypeWeWantToAddExtensionTo) extends AnyVal {
  def extensionMethod1() = ???
}

val v: TypeWeWantToAddExtensionTo = ???
v.extensionMethod1()
```

expands to

```
fooOps(v).extensionMethod1()
```

so if there is another `fooOps` definition in scope then it could cause name conflict.

Starting Scala 3 this is no longer a problem because we do [not](https://www.scala-lang.org/2020/11/06/explicit-term-inference-in-scala-3.html#extension-methods) have to come up with a name for the implicit class, instead we just write

```
extension (v: TypeWeWantToAddExtensionTo) 
  def extensionMethod1() = ???
  def extensionMethod2() = ???
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

> > There may not be any method, member or object in scope with the same
> > name as the implicit class.
>
> Just wondering why this is the case?

The short answer is: because they *are* methods!

The slightly longer answer is: because implicit classes are syntactic sugar for a class and a method.

Remember what we used to write before there were implicit classes:

```scala
final class IntFactorialExtension(n: Int) {
  final def ! = (1 to n) reduce (_ * _)
}

implicit def intFactorialExtension(n: Int) = new IntFactorialExtension(n)

5! //=> 120: Int
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/SFaldvNST0Ore0FrB15nrA)

As defined in [SIP-13 – *Implicit classes*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/implicit-classes.html#description) (which is linked from the document you quoted), an implicit class is simply syntactic sugar for a method (implicit conversion) and a class, just like we used to write by hand before implicit classes [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> An implicit class **must be defined in a scope where method definitions are allowed** (not at the top level). An implicit class is **desugared into a class and implicit method pairing**, where the implicit method mimics the constructor of the class.
>
> The **generated implicit method will have the same name as the implicit class**. This allows importing the implicit conversion using the name of the class, as one expects from other implicit definitions. For example, a definition of the form:
>
> ```scala
> implicit class RichInt(n: Int) extends Ordered[Int] {
>   def min(m: Int): Int = if (n <= m) n else m
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> will be transformed by the compiler as follows:
>
> ```scala
> class RichInt(n: Int) extends Ordered[Int] {
>   def min(m: Int): Int = if (n <= m) n else m
>   ...
> }
> implicit final def RichInt(n: Int): RichInt = new RichInt(n)
> ```

So, because an implicit class desugars into both a name in the *type realm* (a class) and a name in the *value realm* (a method / implicit conversion), it must be legal and valid in both the type realm and the value realm, which for the implicit conversion specifically means that there cannot be another name in the value realm in scope.